# need default value data for registry keys

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

Location- Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender

Name- ProductStatus & ProductType

Location- Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SecurityHealthService

Name- Start & Type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Location- Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender

Name- ProductStatus  = 0

& ProductType  = 2

The other one does not exist on my W10 install, sorry.